# How do I get the size (count) of a generic type class?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

How do I create a generic class where I can get the size (or count) of an item regardless of whether it is an Int, String, etc...

```
class Node<T: Equatable> {

    var item: T? = nil
    var next: Node? = nil

    init(item:T, node:Node?) {
        self.item = item
        self.next = node
    }

    var count:Int { <-------------- this is what I need to fix
        return item.count
    }

}
```

I want to do this so I can compare items like this:

```
let one = Node<Int>(item:1, node:nil)
let two = Node<Int>(item:2, node:nil)

return one.count < two.count <--------- should return true

let str1 = Node<String>(item:"moose", node:nil)
let str2 = Node<String>(item:"cow", node:nil)

return str1.count < str2.count <------- should return false
```

**Update**
I'm running into an issue with normal comparisons now. I get the error, "binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Any?' (aka 'protocol <>')"

```
func search(item:Any) -> Bool {

    var current:Node? = self.head
    var found = false

    while current != nil && found != true {
        if current?.item == item { <---------this is the error line
            found = true
        } else {
            current = current?.next
        }
    }

    return found
}
```

I tried implementing a custom '==' operator in addition to the one for Node comparisons

```
func ==(lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
    return lhs.count == rhs.count
}

func ==(lhs: Any, rhs: Any) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make your Node class conform to Equatable and Comparable, and change your item type to Any?:

```
class Node: Equatable, Comparable {

    var item: Any? = nil
    var next: Node? = nil

    init(item: Any?, node: Node?) {
        self.item = item
        self.next = node
    }
    var count: Int {
        // the trick is here, just conditionally casting to Int or String and return its Int value or the string characters count.
        if let val = item as? Int {
            return val
        }
        if let str = item as? String {
            return str.characters.count
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

---

```
func ==(lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
    return lhs.count == rhs.count
}

func <(lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
    return lhs.count < rhs.count
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let nodeOne = Node(item:1, node:nil)
let nodeTwo = Node(item:2, node:nil)

 print(nodeOne < nodeTwo) // true

let nodeStr1 = Node(item:"moose", node:nil)
let nodeStr2 = Node(item:"cow", node:nil)

print( nodeStr1 < nodeStr2)  //  false
```

Comment: This is a great answer, although I'm running into one issue. I use the '==' operator in the traditional way elsewhere in my program and I keep getting the error: "binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Any?' (aka 'protocol <>').

Comment: For example, in some instances I try comparing "if Node.item == item"...that is where i'm running into issues now

Comment: I can't help you further If you don't show your full code

Comment: Just do the same i did for count property or implement a custom == operator

Comment: I need to see how you are implementing the == operator

Comment: `func ==(lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
    if let lhsInt = lhs.item as? Int,
        let rhsInt = rhs.item as? Int {
        return  lhsInt == rhsInt
    }
    if let lhsStr = lhs.item as? String,
        let rhsStr = rhs.item as? String {
        return  lhsStr == rhsStr
    }
    return false
}`

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error :/....It's having a problem with the 'Any' declaration

Comment: Just compare the node not the node item

Comment: As I said your second question ia unclear. You need to provide a minimum verifiable example.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's comparing a Node of type 'Node' to an item of type 'Any'....it's expecting two Nodes

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find a better way to frame my question. Thank you for your help thus far, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just create a dummy node with the item and compare it

Answer (score 1):

I would advise simply defining a `NodeItem` protocol that requires a `_count` property and `Comparable` conformance, allowing conforming types to implement their own logic for defining how they want the node's `count` to be defined.

```
protocol NodeItem : Comparable {
    // It's prefixed with an underscore to indicate that it shouldn't be used directly
    // by anything other than Node (else it would be confusing for Int to have
    // a count property)
    var _count : Int { get }
}

// conform Int and String to NodeItem, allowing them to define _count
extension String : NodeItem {
    var _count: Int { return characters.count }
}

extension Int : NodeItem {
    var _count: Int { return self }
}
```

You can then constrain your `Node` class' item type to this protocol, and implement `count` by simply returning the `_count` of the `item`:

```
class Node<Item : NodeItem> {

    // I see no reason for item to be optional, as Node must be initialised with one.
    var item: Item
    var next: Node?

    init(item: Item, next:Node?) {
        self.item = item
        self.next = next
    }

    var count: Int {
        return item._count
    }
}
```

```
let one = Node(item: 1, next: nil)
let two = Node(item: 2, next: nil)

print(one.count < two.count) // true

let str1 = Node(item: "moose", next: nil)
let str2 = Node(item: "cow", next: nil)

print(str1.count < str2.count) // false
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that the `item` property of `Node` is strongly typed, allowing the compiler to enforce type-safety – such as preventing the construction of a `Node` where the `Item` type doesn't implement its own `_count` logic or isn't `Comparable`. Also, as it doesn't rely on runtime type-casting, the compiler will have more opportunities for optimisation.

When it comes to implementing your search logic, you can simply equate node items directly, as they're strongly typed. For example, a `LinkedList<Item>` class:

```
class LinkedList<Item : NodeItem> {

    let head : Node<Item>

    init(head: Node<Item>) {
        self.head = head
    }

    func search(item: Item) -> Bool {

        var current : Node? = head

        while current != nil {
            if current?.item == item {
                return true
            }
            current = current?.next
        }
        return false
    }
}
```